# Tabela MySQL com muitos dados

Tags: mysql, algoritmo-de-busca, big-data

**Caso de exemplo:** Tenho um sistema com aproximadamente 5 milhões de registros, é recomendado utilizar uma única tabela do MySQL para salvar, por exemplo `tabela_empresas_brasil`? visto que toda vez que o usuário realizar uma consulta precisará buscar nesses 5 milhões de registros..
Pode ocasionar sobrecarga no servidor? Qual a melhor maneira de desenvolver nesse caso?

Comment: O particionamento da tabela e cache dos itens mais acessados  são opções.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certifique-se de criar índices para suas buscas nessa tabela, ai você não terá problema com sobrecarga, 5 milhões de registros não é um volume de dados a se preocupar apenas para consulta.